# Update table with maximum result of function from another table

Tags: mysql

Suppose the following tables

```
source(
    id INT,
    name VARCAHR
)

dest(
    id INT,
    name VARCAHR
)
```

Where `source` table is filled with both `id` and `name`; and `dest` is filled with `name` only, having `id` set to `null`

It is necessary to update `dest` table and set `id` which is the `id` of most similar `name` (calculated by Levenstein distance) from `source` table

For better understanding this is how I planned it to be ideally (query has syntax error):

```
UPDATE dest
SET dest.id = (
    SELECT source.id, levenstein_ratio(dest.name, source.name) as similarity
    FROM source
    GROUP BY similarity HAVING similarity > 50
    ORDER BY similarity DESC
    LIMIT 1
).id
```

I couldn't make any reasonable query without repeating function.

Is there a way to do it? Efficiency is not crucial but somewhat reasonable solution would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You set dest.id require a single return value from select so you should refactor you query eg: this way

```
UPDATE dest
SET dest.id = (
    SELECT source.id
    FROM source
    GROUP BY levenstein_ratio(dest.name, source.name) 
    HAVING levenstein_ratio(dest.name, source.name) > 50
    ORDER BY levenstein_ratio(dest.name, source.name) DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: I understand, but this requires repetitive call to the same function. I'd like to avoid that

Comment: If you need a working query ......  i don't know another way ..  because (i repeat ) you must have a single result in select  for assign this to the set field......this implies that you can't define the alias similarity and then   if you can't use the alias .. the unique way is repeat the original code ..